# php code to validate textbox values

Tags: php

i have two column in my form..

textbox1

total

user input Data in my textbox like

textbox1 = 501,502,

total = 2

I need validation code..to validate textbox1.

FOR EX

If user enter

total = 2 then  textbox1 accepts only two values like below

textbox1 = 501,502,

if user try to enter more than two values need to echo message...

if i enter 1 in total textbox then it allow user to input only 1 value in textbox1 not more than 1....

below is my code...

I dont have any idea how to validate such condition....plz

```
$textbox1 = $_POST['textbox1']; 
$arr = explode(",", rtrim($textbox1 , ', '));
$total= $_POST['total'];





 public function receipt_exist($arr,$total)
        {
            $errors=array();
            //validation code here

             return $errors;        
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just need to check if the length of `$arr` matches the numeric value in `$total`?

Comment: yes i want to check the length of total to match with length of textbox1...and if not then display error message...

Comment: for ex - if i input total = 2 then it accept only textbox1 = 501,502, thats it........that would not accept more values in textbox1 after that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is check the length of the array, that's simple enough.  Maybe something like this:

```
$textbox1 = $_POST['textbox1']; 
$arr = explode(",", rtrim($textbox1 , ', '));
$total= intval($_POST['total']);

if (count($arr) != $total) {
    // display error message
} else {
    // continue
}
```

The error message is up to you.  You might emit some HTML and end the response, for example.  (If you end the response then you don't need the `else` block, the code would look cleaner without it.  Instead you'd simply continue with the logic after the `if` block.)

Answer (score 0):

or make it by using javascript..

```
<input type="text" id="total" name="total">  
<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="textbox1" onkeypress="return checkInput()">
<script>
function checkInput(){   
        var total = document.getElementById('total').value;
        var textbox1 = document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
        if(total.length*3 < textbox1.length){
             alert("entered value is bigger");
             return false;
       }
}
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sctmad18/)

Comment: Validating in JavaScript would definitely make for a better UX, though he'll still want to validate in PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$textbox1 = $_POST['textbox1']; 
$arr = explode(",", rtrim($textbox1 , ', '));
$total= $_POST['total'];

public function receipt_exist($arr,$total){
  $errors=array();
  if(count($arr)>$total){
   $errors[] = "ERRROR";
  }   
return $errors;        

}
```

Comment: Please do not just post code without explaining what we're looking at.